# What is the standard R way to output results from a script?

Tags: r

I realize that a lot of work in R is done interactively where the output can immediately be seen. However, I usually want my scripts to be user-friendly and descriptive so I want output from my scripts to be minimally verbose.

I'm just still new in R and like to be able to transfer my work into a script for reuse. After searching around a bit on StackOverflow I came up with this result for my script:

```
# Display the results
paste("The number of houses is: ", numHouses, sep=" ")
```

This kind of output in Python could be:

```
print("The number of houses is %d", numHouses")
```

I would also *REALLY* prefer to end my sentences with a period, so append "." at the end of the output in R.

At the moment I do not need the data written to a file. I just want it written to the console. I'm using R Studio.

Comment: `message(paste0("The number of houses is ", numHouses, "."))`

Comment: `sprintf("The number of houses is %d.", numHouses)`

Comment: Thanks @lukeA. I might need that when I do more work with formatted output if there isn't another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use `message` because it can be easily suppressed in cases where the user *doesn't* want output. `cat` and `print` also work, but they don't seem to be handled as well from inside functions or loops. But `cat` can work on a stream of information, and `print` and `message` both take single character string inputs.

```
message(paste0("The number of houses is ", numHouses, "."))
```

Comment: I'll probably accept this answer in a few days unless there is furious discussion over it :) How can the message output be suppressed?

Comment: @RickHenderson If you look closely at the docs at `?message` you'll probably find the answer to suppressing messages. ;)

Comment: This is how I do it all the time now @gregmacfarlane and I find it very useful. Thanks.